# How to display a picture so it doesn't look connected

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an image of a wave, and I want to make it animated.
**How can I remove the stitches that connect the images?**

this is what I made so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS (SCSS)**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503455637927-730bce8583c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2700&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  .wave {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 134px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/938837/wave.svg");
    animation: wave 10s linear infinite;

    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 134px;

    }
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    background-position: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 760px;
  }
}
```

**SVG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="999px" height="134px" viewBox="0 0 999 134" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="wave" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
            <path d="M0,134 L0,42.2253747 C17.4511761,28.1474908 42.9411378,28.9929687 61.2033313,42.0015294 L167.733031,117.88497 C181.802595,127.907028 200.048695,129.956904 215.991332,123.306596 L349.698927,67.5318352 C362.723379,62.0988175 377.437251,62.422763 390.209969,68.4237399 L500.138179,120.071059 C518.142964,128.530206 539.449556,125.511425 554.395844,112.383672 L667.77663,12.7980841 C686.560807,-3.700595 714.644244,-3.7888782 733.531778,12.5913759 L843.37411,107.85237 C861.00964,123.146821 886.88145,124.202875 905.704833,110.396629 L998.649267,42.2253747 L998.649267,134 L0,134 Z" id="Line"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[The code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edensharvit/trb7kpzf/)

**Answer**
Thank you @ksav for recommending me to round the values of the edges

(from **L998.649267** to **L999**) in my SVG file.

Your solution was great!!!
If there is a way to mark your answer as most recommended, I will do that.

Comment: You probably want to ensure that the line within the SVG finishes on the edge of the image. It looks like it goes `L998.649267` as opposed to `L999`.

Comment: In wave background image, gap is there on right side. Fix that.

Comment: Adding `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to the group is fixing your problem but gives you a jagged edge. Not a solution.

Comment: yeah, the gap is what I try to fix. Do you have any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: just open your wave svg file in your adobe illustrator and extend a little bit from right side and save the file.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: Hi @Rob, thanks for notifying me. I changed it as it requires